# Symfony4 ENV Prod

Tags: symfony4

I have a problem with symfony4 when I set my variable APP_ENV = prod and APP_DEBUG = 1 the page is displayed correctly but when I change APP_DEBUG = 0 I have this error message. Do you have an idea why?

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>   The server returned a "404 Not Found".
>   Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked in your log files (`var/log/dev.log`) to see what is missing?

Comment: This is not enough information. What does it mean - works correctly. What can you see? What's in the log files? You can try to look up your web server logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

When switching from prod to dev or switching from debug to non-debug, there could be some caching issues. Try to clear your cache after changing your environment settings with:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

or remove the var/cache folder.

If there is no cache, then symfony will try to create one. If you start in an dev environment and then want to use the prod environment with the same cache, then this will mostly results in problems.